# data not inserting into database using mysqli and php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, http-post, sql-insert

I'm trying to write the contents of a POST to our mysql DB. The data does not seem to be inserting, and I'm not receiving any errors. The db login I'm using has remote access as well. The query itself is getting the correct data from the variables. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I wrote the value of my query into the error_log, when I directly insert via workbench the insert is successful.

```
   [17-Feb-2017 07:02:47 America/Los_Angeles] INSERT INTO         
   consolidated.ACI_BNF (ConsumerName, AccountNumber,    
   NotificationType, ConfNumber, PaymentDate, PaymentAmount, 
   PaymentFee, FundingType, PaymentMethod, ProductMethod, 
   ImportDate)
   VALUES ('JOHN DOE', '00123546', 'CREATE', '000123456',    '2017-02-17', '444.37', '4.95 ', 'CREDIT CARD', '', 'ONE_TIME_PAY', '2017-02-17T10:02:47')
```

PHP Code

```
$hostname_Database = "somedb";
$database_Database = "consolidated";
$username_Database = "username";
$password_Database = "password";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_Database, $username_Database,$password_Database, $database_Database); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO consolidated.ACI_BNF (ConsumerName, AccountNumber, NotificationType, ConfNumber, PaymentDate, PaymentAmount, PaymentFee,  
FundingType, PaymentMethod, ProductMethod, ImportDate)
VALUES ('$AccountHolderName', '$accountNumber', '$notification',   
'$ConfirmationNumber', '$PaymentDate', '$PaymentAmount', '$PaymentFee',   
'$FundingType', '$PaymentMethod', '$ProductMethod', '$ImportDate')";


   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
     }

   $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 
   if (!$result) {
    printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
    }

     echo "Query run. Inserted UserID " . $mysqli->insert_id . "<br />";


        mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Print the query out to the screen, copy it, and try inserting it manually.

Comment: There is no way for us to validate your VALUES (code part not here), so what you can do is 1. Print the query before execute it, to check for errors 2. Do a `SHOW WARNINGS` after the insert, to get more information from the sql server. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-warnings.html

Comment: try `mysqli_real_escape_string` for date

Comment: Its been fixed. Turned out the mysql account did not have insert access from remote clients. I wish the error log could've told me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
$mysqli->connect_errno
```

Instead of:

```
mysqli_connect_errno()
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you forgot write name of submit. for example :

in html :

```
     <input type="submit" name="submit" >
```

in php :

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"})){
           $user = $_POST["username"];
    }
    ...
```